# What is the closest synonym to 'overpopulation'?

Tags: nouns, synonyms

I've been looking for a word which is very close semantically to 'overpopulation'. Popular Internet dictionaries show words like 'overcrowding' or 'congestion', which are too general for me. I know that there is no such thing as 'the exact synonym', but if anybody can think of anything more adequate than my examples, I would be delighted if that person shared it with me.

Comment: Inhabitant-saturation.

Comment: You haven't given us any indication what you want in this synonym. Formal o informal? Technical or non-technical? Do you know it already but just can't seem to remember it? Do you just want to add some variety to a passage you're writing? We have _no_ idea what you want. Did you check a thesaurus first?

Comment: I'm having difficulty splitting 'abstruse' and 'recondite'. They both seem to be used in exactly the same way. Very rarely.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the phrase *exceedance of carrying capacity* to describe an overpopulation?

> The **carrying capacity** of a biological species in an environment is
>   the maximum population size of the species that the environment can
>   sustain indefinitely, given the food, habitat, water and other
>   necessities available in the environment.

Or simply, a  *teeming population*.

Answer (score 0):

*Proliferation* is a nice word that I would play with in the context you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the show. But, as a student of this issue, I would note that "overpopulation" has become a controversial phrase; many reflexively reject the concept out of hand. Maybe try: seeking "optimum population," a phrase that's more current and less apt to incite grow-the-economy-at-all-costs types.

Answer (score 0):

An **[overabundance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/overabundance)** of cows in a barn [may cause methane explosions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-25922514).